# How to give TFS2015 access to the external users?

Tags: tfs-2015

Could anyone help on How to give TFS 2015 access to the external users i.e clients and NON-AD group?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please share what you have tried also. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the user in your domain on premise TFS, you can add these users by creating the users in the TFS box as a windows user.

Check this blog: http://chamindac.blogspot.sg/2014/06/create-non-ad-user-in-tfs-in-domain.html

Comment: Then what if you do not want to add ANY users to ANY local Windows or Domain computers. but still want a on premise tfs ?